# Selenium Webdriver - Find dynamic id from li/a

Tags: java, dynamic, find, webdriver

I am trying to select a value(Bellevue) from a `li`(it looks like a dropdown but it isn't).The problem is that its `id` changes everytime the page loads.
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

This time the id is: `ui-id-23`,but the number,23,will be changed next time so this will not work.If I expand the `<a id="ui-id-23..."` I get the name 'Bellevue' but every character surrounded by < strong >  < /strong > mark-up.

I can't find it after it's classname because both values from li have the same class,`ui-menu-item`.

I tried after xpath:`"//a[contains(text(),'Bellevue')]"` but I get the error:`Unable to locate element...`

Do you know any solution for this?I am using Selenium Webdriver in Java and TestNG.
Thanks!

**Update**

So I managed to find that element by using:

`WebElement value = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[id^='ui-id-']")).get(3);
value.click();` .

but in my application i am using page objects and i look after elements using @FindBy(how.HOW.....).Do you know how I can use .get(3) with @FindBy?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a CSS selector on the ID:

```
a[id^='ui-id-']
```

This says "Find all of the `a` elements that have an ID that start with `ui-id-`"

If you want to find the second item, then do:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[id^='ui-id-']"))[1]
```

The `[1]` will select the second item on the page.

Comment: i will try this tomorrow and I will give you a feedback

Comment: Hi,i am using the @FindBy so i tried:`@FindBy(how=How.CSS,using = "a[id^='ui-id-']"[1])` but i got an error `the type of expression must be an array`.

Comment: so I managed to get that value with this line: `WebElement article = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[id^='ui-id-']")).get(3);` ...
do you know if I can make this with @FindBy?

Comment: Yes.  `@FindBy(cssSelector = "a[id^='ui-id') List<WebElement> elements` is what you want. Then in your code, just do `elements.get(3)`;

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jQuery [`uniquId()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/) method is used to populated the id, so it will always start with `ui-id-`. You can use jQuery selector to select element whose id starts with `ui-id-`

```
WebElement webElement = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return $( 'input[id^="ui-id-"]').get(0);");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,but I get a sysntax error...i think some "" are not correct

Comment: still getting `Syntax error on tokens,missplaced constructs` .So at the begginingg of the page I declared `public JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;`(after driver was declared as `public WebDriver driver`). And then i called that `executeSript`...I think the problem is elsewhere.It seems like it can't recognise js.

Comment: @AdiCrainic let me know if you are able to figure out the cause

Comment: I followed @Nathan Merrill `s answer.I've updated my question

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use xpath avoiding using of id. For example, `//a[@class=''ui-corner-all ui-state-focus ][2]`

Comment: sorry..I can't search after its class..i mentioned in my question.

Comment: oh, my fault. I've edited answer a bit. If you add `[2]` WebDriver will search the second occurrence of this xpath.

Comment: i will try this tomorrow and I will give you a feedback

Answer (score 0):

First get the tag name in which your id attribute has been defined.

```
 WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.tagName(tagName));
 String strId = ele.getAttribute("id").startsWith("ui-id-");

 driver.findElement(By.id(strId)).click();
```